# Могу ли я задать импорты по умолчанию в Visual Studio, Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d, visual-studio, импорт, using

Сейчас у меня каждый скрипт в Юнити по умолчанию имеет 3 импорта (using):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
```

Но мне нередко пригождается UI, поэтому мне постоянно приходится вручную добавлять `using UnityEngine.UI`, а еще мне почти никогда не нужны первые 2 импорта.

Так могу ли я как-то настроить под себя те импорты, которые я хочу чтобы были по умолчанию.

Comment: Нет. Если ты **НАСТОЛЬКО** ленивый, поставь `IDE Rider`, в отличае от `VS`, он сам дописывает  используемый `using` и забей на неиспользуемые.

Comment: @Yaroslav Почему же нет? У юнити, как и у студии все сводится к неким "темплейтам", которые без труда можно в любом текстовом редакторе подстроить под себя. Вот например инструкция для [Unity](https://support.unity3d.com/hc/en-us/articles/210223733-How-to-customize-Unity-script-templates), а вот пути к этим шаблонам для [VS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/700086/6808809).

Comment: Ярослав, а что так агрессивно то сразу? Просто надоедает постоянно писать одно и то же в каждом новом скрипте. EvgeniyZ, спасибо, но если вы напишите это в ответе, а не комментарии, то я смогу принять ваш ответ

Comment: @МаксимФисман Если пишете человеку, то обращайтесь через @, иначе он не получит уведомление. За раз можно только 1 человека оповестить. По поводу ответа - я бы написал наверно, если хотел?) Так что оставляю это на вас, можете составить сами полноценный ответ.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, когда я пытаюсь сохранить файл txt в проводнике, то мне выдаётся ошибка, что нет прав, обратитесь к администратору или владельцу файла. Установка файлу полного доступа в свойствах не решает проблему... Если нужно, могу заскринить

Comment: Запустите редактор, которым пытаетесь изменить, изначально от администратора, а затем, в нем откройте файл.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил проблему следующим способом: открываем блокнот от имени администратора (у меня на Windows 10 путем `поиск -> Блокнот -> ПКМ -> Открыть от имени администратора`.

Открываем файл по пути `C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\[Версия Юнити]\Editor\Data\Resources\ScriptTemplates\81-C# Script-NewBehaviourScript.cs`. Устанавливаем какие начальные данные хотим иметь в новом скрипте.

**Вуаля!**