# Автоподключение UnityEngine.UI

Tags: c#, unity3d

Насколько я понимаю, есть возможность настроить автоподключение данной (возможно и других) библиотеки при возникновении ее необходимости в коде.

Подскажите, как это организовать ?

Comment: ниче не понял. если она тебе нужна, то просто подключи ее в `using`

Comment: Зависит от IDE, некоторые сами прописывают используемые (не VS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я уже задавал такой вопрос вот здесь: [Могу ли я задать импорты по умолчанию в Visual Studio, Unity?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1170075/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%b2-visual-studio-unity)

Ответ: Открываем блокнот от имени администратора (на Windows10 поиск -> Блокнот -> Открыть от имени администратора.

Открываем файл по пути C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor[Версия Юнити]\Editor\Data\Resources\ScriptTemplates\81-C# Script-NewBehaviourScript.cs. Устанавливаем какие начальные данные хотим иметь в новом скрипте - просто подписываем сверху необходимые импорты.

Если вам нужно подключать ее не всегда, а **только** при `возникновении необходимости`, то после написания чего-то, что требует еще не добавленного импорта, можно нажать Alt+Enter (если не ошибаюсь - точнее написано в ошибке о неподключении библиотеки) и она подключиться сама.

Comment: Благодарю. По существу и аргументированно .